# Code signing fails from Terminal for cordova build - xcode8

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode8, code-signing

I get the below error when I do a build from Terminal with the command

***cordova build ios --device***

---

> Check dependencies No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No
>   "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "**********"
>   with a private key was found. Code signing is required for product
>   type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

---

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3D99.png)

I have an Enterprise Account and I am trying to use a "iPhone Distribution" for In-house distribution

With the same settings, I am able to build the app from Xcode directly (So, I don't think there is an issue with Keychain Access storing my certificate)

But, I want the build to be created from Terminal for automation.

Can anyone help..

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

The Cordova build is failing because you're not specifying the `--codeSignIdentity`or `--provisioningProfile` in your Terminal command. Just pass through the same ones that you've specified in your target settings in Xcode.

For more information on configuring code signing for your Cordova app, check the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#signing-an-app).